# Opencart 1.5; How to add 15% to dollar amount passed to Authorize.net gateway

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I am using opencart version 1.5 and Authorize.net as my gateway.  As my shipping and tax needs to be calculated after purchase I need to be sure and authorize an amount above the purchase price.  Does anyone know how to add a percentage amount to the 'authorize' amount sent to the gateway? From much simpler past experience, I am guessing I need to intercept the amount variable directly after the customer clicks PURCHASE at the checkout prior to posting to the gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to go to the below file:

> catalog\controller\payment\authorizenet_*

Search for below code

> $data['x_amount']

And add below line after the above line:

> $data['x_amount'] = $data['x_amount'] + ((15*
>   $data['x_amount'])/100);

Comment: Why not `1.15 * $data['x_amount'] ` ?